Snaplet restore but ignore schema
I am currently using this command npx @snaplet/snapshot ss r --no-reset to clone a snapshot to a database, this command works great but it does fully reset some schemas that I dont want to be reset such as my 'vault' schema. How when running this restore command can I have it ignore resetting a schema? Ultimately I want something like this npx @snaplet/snapshot ss r --no-reset --exclude-schema=vault

You can try the following steps
You can reverse your logic by first excluding the vault which you don't want modified by using pg_dump.

With pg_dump, you can control which schemas to include or exclude with this command:

pg_dump --exclude-schema=vault --file=schema_dump.sql --dbname=your_db



The next step is just to restore the data after your command: npx @snaplet/snapshot ss r --no-reset

You can then restore the dumped file:
psql --dbname=your_db --file=schema_dump.sql

Alternatively,
You can create a customised bash script for this purpose.
Here is a code snippet to guide you.
#!/bin/bash

pg_dump --schema=vault --file=latest_vault_backup.sql --dbname=my_db

# using npx
npx @snaplet/snapshot ss r --no-reset

# restore the vault
psql --dbname=your_db --file=latest_vault_backup.sql


If you want to explicitly do that, you might need to create a snaplet.config.ts file. You might not be able to do that via your command line. see ref: docs

thanks, is there anyway to do it with just snaplet though?

You are welcome, you might need to create a snaplet.config.ts file for that, see docs for reference
